# Edge browser issue when using scale css

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a scroll jacking on a video that scales the video container using css transform. It's working fine on all browsers however in IE and edge it does the scale transform but the video gets pixelated when the video is scaling up.

CSS

`transform: translateY(0) scale(3,3);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(3,3);; /* android, safari, chrome */
 -moz-transform: translateY(0) scale(3,3);; /* old firefox */
 -o-transform: translateY(0) scale(3,3);; /* old opera */
 -ms-transform: translateY(0) scale(3,3);; /* old IE */
 transform: translateY(0) scale(3,3);; /*standard */
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to refer links below may give you some more information.

[transform property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/jj127312(v=vs.94))

[CSS Demo: transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

If still not work then I suggest you to provide your full sample code.

We will try to make a test with it and try to find a solution for it.